# how to solve this error Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Grammar::parameterize() must be of the type array, string given

Tags: laravel, insert

I got this problem trying to get id by comparing user input with data in database. I am new in this and I tried some solution which not help at all.

Below is my controller code:

```
public function assign(Request $request)
  {
        $courselist = new Courselist;
        
        $coursecode = $request->input('coursecode'); 
        $courseid = DB::select("select id from course where course_code = '$coursecode'");
        
        $courselist -> course_id = $courseid;
        $courselist -> coordinator = $request->input('coordinatorname');
        $courselist -> internal = $request->input('imname');
        $courselist -> external = $request->input('exname');
        $courselist -> dean = $request->input('deanname');
        $courselist -> save();
        
        return back()-> with('alert-success','Data successfully added!');   
  }
```

Comment: let me know if i need to show other codes as I am kinda new in this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$course = DB::table("your table name")->where("course_code ", "=", $coursecode)->first();

$courselist -> course_id = $course->id;
```

try this i hope it will work.

Comment: omg it works thank you so much...may I ask why my coding not working